# Подчеркнуть текст Android

Tags: android, java

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Вот такой код, выводит обычный текст, как мне его подчеркнуть линией внизу?
или может быть можно выделить в стринг файле?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String htmlTaggedString  = "<u>Подчеркнутый текст</u>";
Spanned textSpan  =  android.text.Html.fromHtml(htmlTaggedString);
tvTitle.setText(textSpan);
```

Answer (score 4):

Программно делается так:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
String s=tv.getText();
SpannableString ss=new SpannableString(s);
ss.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(ss);
```

Если хотите обойтись xml'кой то можно попробовать декларировать текст в string.xml с HTML тегами:

```
<resource>
   <string name="MyString"><u>underlined text</u></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: В xml такое не прокатывает... Пытался, а вот кодом это не подходит...

Comment: @dajver, работает же XML
android:text="@string/forget_password"   - это в TextView
<string name="forget_password"><u>Забыли пароль</u></string>
- а это в strings.xml

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно из разметки установить подчеркнутый текст, то определите переменную в файле ресурсов с тегами `<u>Подчеркнутый тексе</u>`

```
<resources>
...
<string name="name_of_resourse"><u>I\'am already a user LOG-IN</u></string>
...
</resources>
```

и устанавливайте ее где нужно в разметке